# How do I assign the right type signature to this curried function in typescript?

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, currying, ramda.js

I am new to typescript & generics and working with a Maybe monad. I have created this small utility function using Ramda:

```
const fromEmpty = R.ifElse(hasLength, Just, Maybe.zero);
```

The closest signature I can infer from this is:

```
type EmptyFunc<T> = (val: T[]) => Maybe<T[]>;
```

It's a function takes in an array and returns a function that returns a Maybe of that array.

I tried doing

```
const fromEmpty(<U extends EmptyFunc<U>) = R.ifElse(hasLength, Just, Maybe.zero);
```

But that doesn't work. It returns `error TS1005: ',' expected.`

What is the right way to work with curried functions in typescript?

Answer (score 1):

The declaration

```
type EmptyFunc<T> = (val: T[]) => Maybe<T[]>;
```

declares a family of different function types `EmptyFunc<number>`, `EmptyFunc<string>`, etc., each of which works for only the specified type `T`.  You probably meant

```
type EmptyFunc = <T>(val: T[]) => Maybe<T[]>;
```

which declares the type `EmptyFunc` of a single generic function that works for all types `T`.  Then to apply this type to `fromEmpty`, just write:

```
const fromEmpty: EmptyFunc = R.ifElse(hasLength, Just, Maybe.zero);
```

(I'm unable to test this myself since you didn't give the definitions of `hasLength`, `Just`, and `Maybe`.)  If that wasn't what you were asking, please clarify the question.